# TeX math interacts with italic and bold formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, markdown

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14940/set-theoretic-definition-of-a-natural-number/14943#14943), I noticed a math bug that looks like an interaction between the parser and the TeX system. When you have a word that starts with math and then has italics or bold later, the italics or bold is formatted correctly in the preview, but not formatted correctly in the final output of the answer.

For example, if you type `$x$-**word**`, what you get in the preview is the letter $x$ followed by **word** in bold, as desired. However, in the final output you get $x$ followed by *word* in italics, not bold, with visible asterisks.

Similar problems happen if you enter `$x$-*word*`. In that case you don't get any italics in the final output, just two visible asterisks.

I need to point out that putting the bold in front, like `**$x$-word**` isn't a solution, because that makes the symbol $x$ bold. There are cases in mathematics where the bold actually has a semantic value, and even when it doesn't the standard convention is not to put math in a bold font.

Also, I hit another difference between the preview display and the final display when editing the previous paragraph: if you remove the second backslash and compare preview to final output you will see it.

Comment: Oh, like [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234)?

Comment: Part of this maybe related to the [broken regexp](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/italics-emphasized-text-not-working-after-a-mathematical-formula) observed before.

Comment: @J.M.: Strange, at the first like it says "status-completed" ...

Comment: @J.M. it is probably related, but different. As in the first thread you linked to it appears that a fixed has already been deployed for *that* bug.

Comment: Let's see how it is in comments: $\LaTeX$-*italic* and $\LaTeX$-**bold** ... yeah, it's worse here. Maybe use `\textbf` for the time being?

Comment: @J. M.: Thanks, I looked but didn't find those. However, the first one is marked "completed", while this is still broken. The difference may be the space (or lack of space) between TeX and markdown. (I will also add a markdown tag to my question.)

Comment: @Willie Wong: do they really use regexes to implement markdown?

Comment: Well, I am not the brightest bulb when it comes to programming, but how else do you implement/parse a mark-up language besides searching for and pairing delimiters?

Comment: @Willie Wong: the stereotypical way to parse a programming language is to break up the input into a stream of tokens with a "lexer", then use a parser to make a parse tree. Sometimes it is possible to just make in-text replacements using regular expressions, but for more complicated languages the code can be much more complicated. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Overview_of_process for a summary. I have no idea what system is used for the stackexchange engine, but this problem looks more like a "lexer" error than a "parser" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky.

Basically, the `-` was getting eaten in a processing pass* causing us to treat the `*italic*` or `**bold**` as intra-word (and thus ignored).  This has been fixed on dev, and should go out sometime tonight.

Naturally, only new or edited posts will be affected.

<sub>*Most of our [markdown implementation](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) is open source.  And yes, it is sadly mostly regular expressions glued together.  Markdown is shockingly resistant to classical compilation.  The [spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) is rather... non-technical.</sub>